# Use PGP public key to cipher with Windows CryptoApi in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, cryptoapi, gnupg

I don't know if this is possible at all. A pair of RSA keys are generated with GNUPG, and the public key is exported to a file. My program receives such file and then it has to encrypt some data with the public RSA key in that file. The program is written in C/C++ and it won't use external libraries, so all I can use is Windows CryptoApi functions (CryptStringToBinary, CryptDecodeObjectEx, CryptImportPublicKeyInfo, etc).

This method works with a public 2048 bit RSA key in PEM format encoded in base64:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAnCEy2jOlwK8qVxAHddaD
J6u8u/D0h8nOexco6Xg8iu7DnZOrKPL/1pTL1pwH5GLp0bsb/NfkxetijIb/C4h7
37y6bZPC8V+Koi2jz2lNCNOF4jWuD9Dw8mYnOeH+HpVkKTDVry824i2+qihWM1s/
DwVNUh4C50asnFl64Qd9ycbE3jDr4+yzeBDC7Pirm21OFVUZhTzNzuT5UQzGidvw
2pomYnDM6NOwoIyrBOP0J4CCGbJnZMsf+Dsya/t9tR0cKgFl1Zh0W/V1eJ8Ud7Yq
vIwGeStNeIcjoVkPGh4Hu1Uj0YHXZeTyy4LYo8OUWIipQEJ/dL4TLd0/uD8cr1LR
TwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

But the key exported with GPG looks quite different:

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2
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=R8UZ
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

Although it's a 2048 bit key as well. If I trim the blank lines and the header, CryptStringToBinary succeeds and translates it into a binary format, but CryptDecodeObjectEx fails (GetLastError() returns 0x8009310B). Removing the checksum didn't work either.

I'm a bit lost here so, basically, Is there a way to obtain a RSA public key exported with GPG and use it to encrypt data with Windows CryptoApi?

Thank you.

Comment: OpenPGP uses its own format not only for keys, but also for encrypted content. If you're trying to encrypt in a manner such that the recipient will be able to decrypt using GnuPG, you won't be able to do so using the Windows Crypto API. Just to make sure you're aware of that.

Comment: Ok, I suspected it but wasn't really sure. Then, is there any open source C/C++ library I can use to encrypt with OpenPGP public keys? Thank you.

Comment: I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Converting OpenPGP Keys to PEM

Extracting the RSA public key from an OpenPGP key and conterting it to PEM format is possible. [Sysmisc has an article about converting to and from OpenPGP keys in different ways](http://www.sysmic.org/dotclear/index.php?post/2010/03/24/Convert-keys-betweens-GnuPG%2C-OpenSsh-and-OpenSSL). For the way OpenPGP to PEM, it boils down to:

```
gpgsm -o  secret-gpg-key.p12 --export-secret-key-p12 0xXXXXXXXX
openssl pkcs12 -in secret-gpg-key.p12 -nokeys -out gpg-certs.pem
```

### OpenPGP has its own Message Exchange Format

Yet a caveat, if you want to encrypt to an OpenPGP user, he will not be able to read any (Open, ...)SSL encrypted information using an OpenPGP implementation like GnuPG. OpenPGP not only uses a different key format, but also another message exchange format.

If you want to send OpenPGP messages, use [GPGME](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gpgme/) to interface GnuPG from C, there might also be other libraries for doing so.